# jQuery(.filter): how to use numerical range instead of .lenght<#?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure about how I would use a numerical range such as 0 to 159, instead of **.length<3**. Would greatly appreciate any help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('TD.green.center').filter( function(){ return $(this).text().length<3; } ) .parent().hide()
});
```

Comment: how would i go about implementing that in the current code?

Comment: just replace 3 by 160

Comment: no, that says to hide the parent then if the length is 160 characters long, which is an unfathomable big length of letters or numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseInt` to convert string to integer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('TD.green.center').filter( function(){
        return parseInt($(this).text())<160;
    }).parent().hide()
});
```